# How to have an RGB value not go over the 255 limit in OpenCv?

Tags: python, opencv

I want to add 100 to the blue value. However in my case I want to have a check happen at every pixel coordinate to check if it goes over the 255 value, it stays at 255.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('cake.jpeg')

b,g,r = cv2.split(img)

if b.all() <= 155:
    b += 100

img = cv2.merge((b,g,r))

cv2.imwrite('edited cake.png', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Note: Calculated 255 - 100 = 155 for check statement.

However the if statement doesn't seem to have any effect on preventing the 255 limit from going over.

Comment: You shouldn't need to check at all. OpenCV calculates addition with `saturate`: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga10ac1bfb180e2cfda1701d06c24fdbd6

Comment: Please do not use the tag [tag:opencv-python]. Per the tag description, "THIS TAG IS PENDING REMOVAL. Instead, please use [opencv] and [python] tags."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need to check, if you use Python/OpenCV add. It does the clipping for you. So

```
b = cv2.add(b,100)
```

should work without the need to clip (and be very fast).

Alternately, you could do

```
b = (b+100).clip(0,255)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using b.all(), that returns true or false if all elements in b are <= 155 or not.
But then inside the "if" you are adding 100 to ALL members of b.
Try to do the check only on those elements of b that are <= 155

Comment: just making (if b <= 155:) alone is going to give me an error of "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"

Answer (score 0):

One approach is addding 100 to all the values of the `B` channel, then check if the value is greater than 255 set 255.

```py
b, g, r = cv2.split(img)

b += 100
b[b > 255] = 255

img = cv2.merge((b,g,r))
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting `b.astype(np.uint8)` is fine, it will clip the maximum value to `255` automatically just like `np.clip()`.